# In which file can i change my java heap size?

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04

I am using java 8 in my ubuntu 16.04. 
While running a program in java via terminal i got the issue:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`
I am able to find answers like i need to change my heap size with proper arguments, but all the answers mention **what** i need to change, but i want to know **where in which file** i need to change, for permanent change/long duration.
And everytime i run a java application
`Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m`
error appears in the terminal.

Comment: Every Java program you launch has different heap requirements. You change the heap size on the command line, in your terminal, when maunching the program: `java -Xmx...`.

Comment: But then why does the log ```Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m``` appears everytime i run a java application? I am not providing any command line argument while running the application.

Comment: If you execute the following `export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx=8192m -Xms=8192m"` command, would that help the situation? This export statement can be put into your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Probably because you're not launching your app with `java ...` directly, but with a shell script that launches java with various options and displays this message. Look at the content of the shell script. If you told us which program you're talking about, how you launch it, and what the content of the script is, it would be easier for us to understand and help.

Answer (score 0):

Set JVM arguments of Initial & Maximum Heap Size through Terminal.

**-Xms=8192m
-Xmx=8192m**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a bit of researching i found that in my **profile** `export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx1024m` was written,due to which in logs it was appearing every time.

The profile is generally used for setting environment variables system-wide . Probably that's the answer to my question. A particular file where we can change the heap size of java system wide.